# How to install kernel modules using debhelper

Tags: linux, kernel-module, debhelper

I have a Makefile that builds a .ko binary, there is a main package with an application in which there is a directory debian/ with all the necessary files to build the package. The question is where to specify and how, so that when the package is unpacked, the modules are assembled and midprobe is made for them.Found tools like dh_installmodules and dkms but couldn't find any example how to use them.

Comment: The proper way is to create a standard DEB package with DKMS helpers. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS, https://github.com/dell/dkms, and so on...